# How to add robust search functionality in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I would like to add search functionality in my Angular app in a way that when a user types something, he/she gets all the possible suggestions in a dropdown. I've heard that it can be done by finding the search string in an array. Do I have to include regular expressions when I loop through the array in order to get the proper suggestion functionality? Or is there an api or angular library to do that for me?

Comment: What type of data are you trying to search for? Blog articles, user accounts, etc...?

Comment: You can take hint from this article :https://levelup.gitconnected.com/implement-search-feature-on-a-web-page-in-plain-javascript-adad27e48

Comment: @CodingSomething Just plain blog posts. Nothing fancy

Comment: If you're looking for the fancier version, Algolia is a great option to start. Since you're not loading everything into the JS array (Each blog post) you won't be able to do the whole search thing from the frontend.

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi Can you provide a screenshot of the page? When I visit the page, it says I have to upgrade in order to read the article. How pathetic!

Comment: @CodingSomething thanks man! This thing look dope!!!

Comment: Happy to help. Will write a bit more depth answer in a minute.

Comment: @CodingSomething The only problem is that my whole site is going to be crawled by an AI. Which I think might hurt privacy. Is there a simple 101 solution without getting involved into all those AI fanciness?

Comment: What type of database are you using for Post storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not looking to just search the available page, you'd need to implement a search service to return the search results for you. Since you won't be loading all the blog pages, Javascript cannot effectively search all of your documents for you.

Additionally, searching for things using Javascript on the frontend with a massive dataset would render the browser unusable. So you can use an external search service provider like Algolia for start.

https://www.algolia.com/pricing/

They have a 50K/month free tier and it is plenty enough when you're starting. If you're looking for something much simpler, you can index the available blog posts and use a search script to get your search string and then return a JSON output as API response.

If you're trying to build up something of your own, you can look into ElasticSearch or Apache Solr. Both are battle-tested solutions and Algolia has some similarities to ElasticSearch.